# How to extract the values from a gridded data only along a straight line consisting of multiple latitude and longitude pair points

Tags: command-line-interface, cdo-climate

I have gridded 4D (lon*lat*plev*time) data, where lon and lat represent longitude and latitude, and plev designates the vertical pressure level. I want to extract the data only along a straight line of multiple longitude-latitude pair points so that I can finally obtain 3D (x*plev*time) data, where x represents the dimension of lon-lat pair points. Now, the straight line has 781 longitude-latitude pair points. However, the sizes of the longitude and latitude in the gridded data are 501x1 and 901x1, respectively.

Earlier, I successfully extracted the value from the same 4D data only for a station location (i.e., only a latitude-longitude point) using the following CDO command line:

```
cdo -remapnn,"lon=77.222_lat=28.588" data.nc data_NewDelhi.nc
```

But this time I want to extract data from the same gridded data but only along the straight line of 781 latitude-longitude pair points, and then store the data in the new netcdf file. Thus, the final netcdf file should have a size of `781 * plev * time`.
So, my question is: Is there a command line in CDO to perform this operation?

Comment: How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Welcome to SO. While I'm sure people on here can help you, this is a programming forum. Please revise the question so that it is purely about programming and doesn't require any scientific knowledge. I work with CDO all the time, but I have no idea what CALIPSO is. Just write it as a programming question, and then we can help

Comment: Hello @RobertWilson, I modified my question again to make a pure programming question. I believe that this will not require any scientific knowledge. Can you please guide me to solve this problem?Is there any way to do this calculation using CDO?Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this using CDO you first need to create an unstructured grid file. The example below will work for 2 data points. Replace it with the 70 grid points you need. Just call a file grid and put the following in it.

```
gridtype = unstructured
gridsize = 2
xvals = 0 10
yvals = 0 10
```

Once you have defined that file, you can regrid in CDO in a similar way to what you have shown:

```
cdo remapnn,grid in.nc out.nc
```

Comment: Dear Robert, Thank you for the response. I just need small clarifications from you. (1) Do you mean that I should create a text file 'grid.txt' (i.e., using the Linux command 'nano grid.txt') and paste the following line in it? (2) For 781 longitude-latitude pair points, the lines should be replaced with 'gridsize= 781' . Right? (3) Do 'xvals' and 'yvals' mean the corresponding values of the longitude and latitude, respectively? I am really looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Please read the CDO user guide, which explains how to set up grids. https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/cdo.pdf

Comment: Okay. I accepted your answer.